# random number creation

Tags: c, random

I need to generate `100` random index in an array of say size 5000 `arr[5000]`. I think `rand()` will use more CPU so I dont want to loop it 100 times. I just want to call it once and want have mechanism to have random array indexes. My idea is to have random value for first 20 indexes, and generate an offset and keep on adding to the generated random value. i.e if `10` is the random value from the first 20 indices,then if the offset is say `6` then my random numbers would be `10,16,22,28...etc`
Do you think this is good idea? Can you please suggest any other?Thanks.

Comment: Calling `rand()` 100 times is not going to be a problem.

Comment: even calling rand() ~10 mil times will not be worse than most of the stuff one could to to avoid calling rand...

Comment: What is the quality of pseudo-randomness you want to achieve? Meaning, how crucial would it be to not have high quality random indices? In any case, I would suggest following what Arvind said about LCGs. If randomness is really crucial, go for an implementation of Mersenne Twister. In any case LCGs are really cheap in terms of CPU.

Answer (score 7):

That is a horrible idea, the resulting values will not be "random" at all.

Just do a loop and call `rand()` for each number you need. It won't "use more CPU" (more than *what*?), it will be fine.

Also, note of course that `rand()` is typically a pseudo-random generator at best, still better than your approach though.

Comment: I just gave an example of '100' for 'arr[5000]', in reality I have `2000 *arr[5000]` and I need to have `2000` random indices from each array of `5000`. Still do you think `rand()` will not hog CPU. Maybe my idea did not have exact random numbers but atleast I have different numbers everytime when `rand()` of specific range gives different number and the offset gets added.

Answer (score 0):

Using rand() is a better idea.  However, if you do really want to do your pseudo-random generator ( which for 99% cases would not be the right answer) then have a look at [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)  -The maths behind it is straightforward, and it is the basis of  libc 's random() implementation. You could try experimenting with the same for fun!  Here's another [link](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/random/).